# Dash Application Python Button for refresh the page

Tags: python, plotly-dash

is there a possibility to write a callback function in Dash (Python) for a button to reload the page (like the updatebutton from the browser?

```
app.layout =html.Div([
            html.Button(id="refresh"),
            ])

@app.callback(Output('???', '???'),
              [Input('refresh', 'n_clicks')])
def refresh(n):

?
return
?
```

Answer (score 12):

solved!

```
html.A(html.Button('Refresh Data'),href='/'),
```

Comment: thanks! I think a looked for an hour for this nice workaround =)

Comment: This will not work is a more advance template that has a multi-page webapp.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to just make a command to refresh the page is: `html.Meta(httpEquiv="refresh",content="60")`.

This command tells the html to refresh the page after 60 seconds.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for ease of use and least overhead.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by [@hussam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6726888/hussam) for a Multi-Page Dash app, you have to adjust it a bit.

Based on the [simple Dash Multi app example](https://dash.plotly.com/urls#simple-example), it would look like this:

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, callback, Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    # represents the browser address bar and doesn't render anything
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),

    dcc.Link('Navigate to "/"', href='/'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Navigate to "/page-2"', href='/page-2'),

    # content will be rendered in this element
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])


@callback(
    Output('page-content', 'children'),
    [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(relative_pathname):
    return html.Div([
        html.H3(f'You are on page {relative_pathname}'),
        html.A(html.Button('Refresh Page'),href=relative_pathname),
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

With the input method for `url`:

```py
[Input('url', 'pathname')])
```

You can get the relative url path, so everything after your main domain.

And with this input, you can setup a a refresh button for this page:

```py
html.A(
    html.Button('Refresh Page'),
    href=relative_pathname
```

see example:

[image]